# Type casting with `as?` to parent type calls child implementation of method

Tags: swift, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
protocol P {
    func f()
}

class Parent: P {
    func f() {
        print("parent")
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    override func f() {
        print("child")
    }
}

let y: P = Child()
if let yy = y as? Parent {
    yy.f()
}
```

When running this in playgrounds, `yy.f()` prints "child", which I do not understand, since I explicitly cast to `Parent`. Does Swift still call the underlying instance's (`Child`'s) implementation, even if I explicitly cast to a different (the parent) type?

Comment: Are you asking why "child" is being printed or are you asking how to ensure that "parent" gets printed?

Comment: This features dynamic dispatch, which will call the instance’s implementation (the `Child` rendition) regardless of the cast. You can employ static dispatch if you don’t want dynamic dispatch (e.g., [here is example](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/f430996d5880b6f6d4c7fd9f701a3e39) with protocol).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> When running this …, `yy.f()` prints "child", which I do not understand, since I explicitly cast to `Parent`. Does Swift still call the underlying instance's (`Child`'s) implementation, even if I explicitly cast to a different (the parent) type?

When you cast to `Parent`, the actual object to which `yy` points is still the original `Child` instance. You’re simply declaring the `yy` variable to only use the interface provided by `Parent`. But if the `Child` overrode any of those `Parent` methods, the `Child` overrides will be used. This is achieved through “dynamic dispatch”, whereby the runtime will figure out which method to actually use dynamically, at runtime.

This sort of polymorphism is often essential for the integrity of our objects in object-oriented programming (OOP).

---

At the risk of  making this even more confusing, it should be noted that Swift can support both “dynamic dispatch” (the behavior you originally observed) as well as “static dispatch” (the behavior you appear to have expected, albeit when using a different paradigm).

Specifically, while OOP patterns (e.g., classes and subclasses) in Swift generally employ dynamic dispatch (as in your example), it should be noted that in protocol-oriented programming (POP), you can choose whether you want to enjoy the flexibility of dynamic dispatch, or the performance benefits of static dispatch.

In the following example, because we did not define the method to be part of the protocol, the default implementation declared in the protocol extension will feature static dispatch:

```swift
protocol Parent { }

extension Parent {
    func f() {
        print("parent")
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    func f() {
        print("child")
    }
}

let y1 = Child()
y1.f()           // child
let y2: Parent = Child()
y2.f()           // parent (!!!)
```

But, with a very simple change (by declaring the method in the protocol definition, as shown below), the protocol enjoys dynamic dispatch:

```swift
protocol Parent {
    func f()
}

extension Parent {
    func f() {
        print("parent")
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    func f() {
        print("child")
    }
}

let y1 = Child()
y1.f()           // child
let y2: Parent = Child()
y2.f()           // child (!!!)
```

Now all of that having been said, all of this dynamic vs static dispatch is an interesting aside, something I mention in case you stumble other static dispatch examples online. If you are doing OOP (with classes and subclasses) just know that you will be enjoying dynamic dispatch. Admittedly, you can achieve static dispatch with classes (notably, a `final` class), but that precludes the class inheritance that your example uses.

If you are interested in learning more about POP, see [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/).

Comment: This is a fantastic answer with way more information on the subject than I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`as?` does not change the type of an object. It checks to see if it can represent it as that type or not, returning `nil` if it can't.

In OOP, a subclass represents an "is a" relationship. So in your inheritance, a `Child` is a `Parent`. The `as? Parent` will always succeed, returning the object.